# Can I host a Slack bot on Bluehost / apache server?

Tags: apache, bots, shared-hosting, slack

So here is the dealio. I'm using the GitHub [BotKit](https://github.com/howdyai/botkit), and was able to run it from Mac terminal and connect right into my Slack channel.

Is there a way to just throw this specific bot up on BlueHost? If not, would you point me in the right direction? I'm looking for a bot I can just host from my current hosting account.

Comment: It depends on what kind of service you have ordered with your provider. BotKit appears to be a node.js app, so I would talk to your provider about what you need to run a node.js app.

Comment: So I have a shared hosting account, but I think what you're saying is I should talk to my host to see if node.js is supported?

Comment: yes, exactly. Most standard webserver accounts only support php, but not node.js

Answer (score 0):

https://ngrok.com/ is a great tool for running it locally during development as well. Lots of Botkit devs go to production with a free heroku account if bluehost isn't up to the task.